# QFontMetrics lacks baseline() method

Tags: qt

QFontMetrics has `accent()` and `descent()` methods, but it lacks the base line.

How do I get the distance from the bottom to the base line?

**EDIT:**

Rephrased in other words, I need to know how to calculate the base line to draw the text as it should go according to font standards, for example:

```
painter->drawText(QPoint(x,fontmetric.height()-fontmetric.descent()),my_text);
```

I am calculating the base line correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question since `ascent()` and `descent()` are relative to the baseline.

Comment: @G.M. ok, if you say accent and descent are calculated from the base line, then how do I calculate the bottom ?

Comment: @G.M.I have made an edit to the question so you could understand what I am trying to achieve